# Git branches automate with source code

Tags: git, bash, github

I am automating the git brnach with my project using shell script. Code Description

- I am going to the source directory
- I am doing remote update
- I am asking user to enter the branch, if user entered wrong branch name
- If the branch doest not exist catch the error and show the user otherwise git checkout and pull the code from the branch

  *

  ```
   #!/bin/bash    
          cd application/src/
          git remote update
          echo "please check all the available branch in git"
          git branch

          echo "Please enter the branch name: "
          read branch_name
          echo "You entered: $branch_name"

          branch=$(git branch)
          files=(branch*)

          select SEL in "${files[@]}"


       do
              if  [[ "$SEL" ] !== '(no branch)']
              then
                  echo "Choose one of the available branch."
                  break



           else
                  git checkout $branch_name
                  git pull origin $branch_name

  done 


      git checkout $branch_name    
      git branch    
      git pull origin $branch_name*
  ```

And i am getting this error.

```
Please enter the branch name:
1.5
You entered: 1.5
ram: line 21: conditional binary operator expected
ram: line 21: syntax error near `]'
ram: line 21: `    if  [[ "$SEL" ] !== '(no branch)']'
```

Can someone help this..

Comment: Your bash syntax is wrong, `!==` is not an operator, you probably meant `!=`. And you also need to remove the square bracket around `"$SEL"`, i.e. `if  [ "$SEL" != '(no branch)']'`

Comment: Its also missing the fi to end condition - if you break it will leave the select but will execute the final command.

Comment: If it is just an example for the question, it's OK, but it doesn't sound like a  good idea to create an interactive shell script to perform an action that the user can do him/herself just throwing a bunch of simple git commands.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you put `[ ]` around `$SEL`. Rewrite it as:

```
if  [ "$SEL" !== '(no branch)']'
```

Comment: But, I dont know at the end of the line i am getting this error                               syntax error: unexpected end of file